# Setting the outer region of Jcrop selection to invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

In the case where an image is overlaid on top of a different image, I would like to have vision of the background image while cropping the foreground image at same time.

Example: Image A is on top of Image B. Jcrop is applied to Image A and when a selection occurs, the area of selection shows only the selected part of Image A. Image B is visible in the background, surrounding the area of selection of Image A.

[image] [image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Image B is the background to a div, and image A is the content of the div? http://jsfiddle.net/tz56qv9f/

Comment: Yes, something like that. The main point is that when the cropping happens, only the selected part of Image A is visible; the rest is not. Image B is still visible in the background as the cropping happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function($){
    $('#target').Jcrop({
        bgColor: '',
        bgOpacity: 0
    });
});
```